# ASPxClientListBox loses values and the first item can not be selected

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, callback, devexpress, servercontrols

On a server control I have a DevExpress [ASPxClientListBox](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientListBoxMembersTopicAll) which is populated dynamically on the client. The server does not need to know anything about it but it is initialized on the server. Normally this server control does not have any problems... however, if I put it in an ASPxCallbackPanel it will work on the first page load but, after a callback, if the ListBox's client side selected index changed event is fired, the selected items values are lost and "undefined" though the keys or "texts" are intact.

On a side note... after a callback the first item in the ListBox can not be selected.... what I mean is that the first item is not highlighted on mouseover or mouseclick.

Links which are slightly relevant but not what I need:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q312536.aspx

I had another link that talked about the "unable to select first item" issue and said that it had something to do with adding the items prior to the control hierarchy being established so the solution was to add the items in the ListBox client side Init event as opposed to the page_load event. I am adding the items after the ListBox has been initialized so I don't see this as a solution ... and I can't find the link now anyways...

Edit: I just found that other link again: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q367021.aspx

Comment: I would suggest you to rebind the listbox every time the callback is made. That is the only feasible option.

Comment: I am never binding the ListBox. I am only using it on the client side. I dynamically create and populate it on the client side. It has no reason to sync with the server because once it is used it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is addressed in the second link you provided. What happens is that...

> ...this function is called immediately when a page is loaded. However,
>   an ASPxListBox hierarchy is not yet ready. The correct way to call the
>   getList function is to handle the ASPxClientListBox event...

To cut the long story short, something like the following won't execute properly if you run it e.g. on load...

```
yourListbox.AddItem("Test1"); 
yourListbox.AddItem("Test2"); 
yourListbox.AddItem("Test3"); 
yourListbox.AddItem("Test4");
```

...but the following should work...

```
s.Properties.ClientSideEvents.Init = 
@"function(s, e) { yourListbox.AddItem('Test1'); yourListbox.AddItem('Test2'); yourListbox.AddItem('Test3'); yourListbox.AddItem('Test4'); }";
```

I guess the first selected-items-problem could have happened for the same or similar reason.